# Running ulimit -d using system() function

Tags: c, linux, ulimit

When I try to execute a c code with the following two lines, ulimit still shows to be unlimited but i want the answer to be 1024.

`system("ulimit -d 1024");
system("ulimit -d");`

Comment: That is because `system(..)` creates a new sub-shell and `ulimit` affects only that sub shell. It is lost when the shell is destroyed upon returning from `system(...)`. Whatever you are trying to do, you should either: 1) wrap in a shell script 2) Hunt for APIs that provide you this functionality *for the current process*.

Comment: You can set these limits on a per-system basis by modifying `etc/security/limits.conf`... it's not clear if this would help you from your question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the ulimit for calling process, use [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html), with arguemnt `RLIMIT_DATA`.

`system()` will fork and the ulimit command only affects the child process, not the calling process.